# ADFS authentication MVC Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, adfs

I need to authenticate user from ADFS using MVC Web Api, where I could send user id and password to API authenticate user.

Comment: [Check out this link and edit your question accordingly please](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using ADFS 4.0 ...

What flow are you using? OpenID Connect, authorisation code grant ...?

The normal endpoints are:

.../adfs/oauth2/authorize

.../adfs/oauth2/token

There are some good samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/ad-fs-development).

(Just to note: When you ask these kinds of qestions always state which version of ADFS, which protocol (OpenID Connect, SAML etc.), which protocol flow ...)